# invalidateQueries stops working if I navigate between Next.js routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

We used `queryClient.invalidateQueries(someQueryKey)` to refetch data in queries and its works well.
Project migrated to `Next.js` and router changed from `react-router` to `next-router` code base stays maximum the same except for router changes.

Now if I navigate from one route to another and then go back, `queryClient.invalidateQueries(someQueryKey)` stops working, all other query calls work as it should useQueris and useMutations .

What weird, when I navigate between the pages queries disappear from `Query Dev Tools` but continue to work, except of `queryClient.invalidateQueries()`. If I refresh the page `Query Dev Tools` starts to show me the correct queries and it starts working correctly until I navigate to another route and back.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue! Let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: You really need to show the code. My best guess is you create a new QueryClient on every page transition, which basically throws away the old cache.

Answer (score 0):

**Discussion moved to**:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/3037

**answer:**
*The following seems to fix the issue, indeed, the previous one was creating a new client every time, so I assume that is why the query invalidations weren't working properly:*

```
export function useReactQueryClient() { 
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(function () {
    return new QueryClient({
      defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
          onError(err) {
            // ....
          },
        },
      },
    });
  });

  return queryClient;
}
```